# SQL Server: Can't DROP and CREATE SP in transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm trying to drop a stored procedure if it exists and then re-create it, all inside a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GET_DATA', N'P') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_DATA]
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_DATA]
    @date datetime2
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        dbo.Products.product_cod AS 'product_cod',
        dbo.Product_Types.name AS 'product_type_name',
        dbo.UM.name AS 'um_name',
        dbo.Products.category_id AS 'category_id',
        dbo.Bins_Products.bin_id AS 'product_bin_id' 

    FROM dbo.Products
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Product_Types on Products.product_type_id = Product_Types.product_type_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UM on Products.um_id = UM.um_id
        LEFT JOIN Bins_Products ON Bins_Products.product_id = Products.product_id
    WHERE
        Products.update_date >= @date
END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ErrorMessage'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

When I run the script above, I get the following errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 31
Must declare the scalar variable "@date".
```

And I have squiggly lines on the SET and @date.

The IF statement and the create statement work fine all by themselves.

Comment: You are missing a GO statement before create procedure, and you cannot use try/catch block.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `DROP PROCEDURE` cannot be done transactionally. Instead, create an empty procedure if it does not exist yet (`CREATE PROCEDURE GET_DATA AS BEGIN RETURN END`), then `ALTER` unconditionally.

Comment: @DeanSavović I tried using GO but that only creates other errors.

Comment: @JeroenMostert , Yes , that seems to be true, I thought you might use a transaction to rollback the drop procedure statement if the create procedure one fails for some reason

Comment: Yeah, just don't drop the procedure at all if you want to ensure it exists. `ALTER` is one statement. The only way it could fail is if the statement itself is incorrect (which you've presumably tested) and the worse that would happen is that you're left with a stub definition of the procedure. If you really wanted to you could have a transaction (by doing everything in `EXEC`) but it's clumsy, since you have to stuff everything in strings (with escaping) and forego syntax highlighting. That's more likely to cause errors than prevent them.

Comment: I would have liked to be able to do this in a single transaction because, on some databases the SP exists and on others it does not exists, that's way I would have liked to check if it exists before hand and drop it then re-create it, otherwise directly creating it would result in errors on some DB's where it already exists, likewise altering it on DB's that don't exist will generate errors.

Comment: Creating it doesn't result in errors if you check whether it exists first, which you would obviously do -- check my answer. The only way that could fail is if there's some sort of race condition with multiple processes trying to create the same procedure at the same time... that's frankly not the sort of thing I'd worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXEC` to create the procedure inside a transaction, but that's very inconvenient, since the whole body needs to be escaped. A better approach is to ensure the stored procedure always exists, and then perform an `ALTER`, which doesn't need a separate transaction:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Foo', 'P') IS NULL
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE Foo AS BEGIN RETURN END;');
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE Foo(@Arg INT) AS BEGIN
    ...
END;
```

Another benefit of this approach (or a drawback, depending on your deployment process) is that this leaves intact any existing permissions on the stored procedure, unlike dropping and creating it.

Comment: Yes, this seems like what I was looking for, even if it does not use a transaction. Thanks

Comment: @dmdany07 - you can wrap it in a transaction just fine. The difficulty is that you a) can't use `TRY`/`CATCH` (because it's *those* that cannot span batches, not transactions as some answers have suggested) and b) once you're in a separate batch, trying to work out whether you should `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` is the difficult to automate bit.

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate that this *can* be done in a transaction, here's a demo script:

```
create procedure dbo.A
as
    select 1 as T
go
exec dbo.A
go
begin transaction
go
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.A', N'P') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    EXEC('drop procedure dbo.A')
END
go
create procedure dbo.A
as
    select penguin from sys.objects --This will fail
go
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.A', N'P') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    commit
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    rollback transaction
END
go
exec dbo.A
```

It produces an error when trying to create a new `A` procedure and the rollback reverts back to the original version of `A`. This can only really work (as here) where creating the new version of `A` results in a hard error such that we can detect that afterwards and decide to `rollback` rather than `commit`.

That being said, I'd still use [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562558/15498) myself.

Comment: You raise another excellent point, though -- deferred name resolution means that `CREATE PROCEDURE` will rarely fail, even if the procedure is absolutely faulty. A hard syntax error or a failed DDL trigger are about the only things the transaction would guard against.

Comment: Thank you for the example, good to know it can be done. Still seems a bit cumbersone. I ended up going with Jereon's example.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure definition has to be in its own batch.  In Management Studio you'd put two lines with

```
go
```

before `create procedure` and after the `end`.  Unfortunately transactions can't span multiple batches.

You could create the procedure inside an `exec` call?  Like:

```
exec ('create procedure dbo.MyProc as ...');
```

Comment: "transactions can't span multiple batches." - I don't know why you think this but it's blatantly untrue. batches and transactions are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, this is my working example.

Modify it as per your tables and requirement.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[_AdvancePaymentDelete]    Script Date: 10/04/2017 15:12:43 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[_AdvancePaymentDelete]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[_AdvancePaymentDelete]
GO

USE [DatabaseName]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[_AdvancePaymentDelete]    Script Date: 10/04/2017 15:12:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_AdvancePaymentDelete] 
(
        @_ADVANCEPAYMENTID_PK uniqueidentifier,
        @_COMPANYID_PK uniqueidentifier ,
        @_COMPANYDETID_PK uniqueidentifier ,
        @_USERID_PK uniqueidentifier
          )
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        SAVE TRANSACTION MySavePoint;
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(MAX) = 'OK';

        BEGIN TRY
UPDATE [dbo].[_ADVANCEPAYMENT] SET _ISDELETED = N'2'

 WHERE _COMPANYID_PK = @_COMPANYID_PK AND _COMPANYDETID_PK = @_COMPANYDETID_PK AND _USERID_PK = @_USERID_PK AND _ADVANCEPAYMENTID_PK = @_ADVANCEPAYMENTID_PK AND _ISDELETED = N'1'

UPDATE [dbo].[_ADVANCEPAYMENTDET]  SET _ISDELETED = N'2'

 WHERE _COMPANYID_PK = @_COMPANYID_PK AND _COMPANYDETID_PK = @_COMPANYDETID_PK AND _USERID_PK = @_USERID_PK AND _ADVANCEPAYMENTID_PK = @_ADVANCEPAYMENTID_PK AND _ISDELETED = N'1'


    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MySavePoint; -- rollback to MySavePoint
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();
    SET @ErrorMessage = 'Error No : '  + CAST ( ERROR_NUMBER() AS nvarchar(MAX)) + CHAR(13) + 'Line No : '  + CAST ( ERROR_LINE() AS nvarchar(MAX))+ CHAR(13) + 'Procedure Name : '  + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)) + CHAR(13) + 'Error Message : '  + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR( @ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        END
    END CATCH

    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END; 

SELECT @ErrorMessage 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do there but I can see a few obvious things wrong with this code, It should look something like this...

Mind you Create procedure must be the only statement inside a batch, which means you cannot wrap drop and create proc in one transaction.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GET_DATA', N'P') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_DATA]
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_DATA]
    @date datetime2
AS
BEGIN                       --<-- Proc body start
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            SELECT 
                dbo.Products.product_cod AS 'product_cod',
                dbo.Product_Types.name AS 'product_type_name',
                dbo.UM.name AS 'um_name',
                dbo.Products.category_id AS 'category_id',
                dbo.Bins_Products.bin_id AS 'product_bin_id' 

            FROM dbo.Products
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Product_Types on Products.product_type_id = Product_Types.product_type_id
                LEFT JOIN dbo.UM on Products.um_id = UM.um_id
                LEFT JOIN Bins_Products ON Bins_Products.product_id = Products.product_id
            WHERE
                Products.update_date >= @date;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
      IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)   -- Check for open transactions before you try to rollback
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      END

    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ErrorMessage'

END CATCH

END                     --<-- Proc body End 
GO
```

Comment: Isthere any way to rollback the drop procedure statement if the create one fails for some reason?